# Laravel search 'LIKE' query in two tables

Tags: php, sql, search, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently trying to set up a search bar that filters the results of two tables, **books** and **categories**.

I have setup relationships for both models where:

Book.php (Model) **(table: id, b_name, b_author, cat_id)**

```
public function bookCategory()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'cat_id', 'id');
}
```

Category.php (Model) **(table: id, cat_name)**

```
public function book()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Book', 'cat_id', 'id');
}
```

BookController.php

```
public function getFilterBooks($input)
{
  $books = Book::with('bookCategory')->where('**cat_name at category table**. 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%'')->get();

  return Response::json($books);
}
```

But obviously this won't work. The reason I'm doing this is because I want to allow users to use the same search bar to filter different columns (which I know how to do it in one table, but not two or more).

Comment: Tried `category.cat_name`?

Comment: you can also use Laravel searchable trait https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable

Answer (score 9):

You can use that.

```
Book::whereHas('bookCategory', function($q) use ($input)
{
    $q->where('cat_name', 'like', '%'.$input.'%');

})->get();
```

See more in http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

EDIT:

```
Book::with('bookCategory')->whereHas('bookCategory', function($q) use ($input)
    {
        $q->where('cat_name', 'like', '%'.$input.'%');

    })->get();
```

You get `cat_name` from relation.